# Django-adminfiles on Django 1.3: ERROR: "browser.link_text" is invalid

Tags: django

I find [django-adminfiles](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-adminfiles/overview) very useful. After I upgraded to Django 1.3 I get the text

```
ERROR: "browser.link_text" is invalid.
```

instead of the filepicker widget. On Django 1.2.5 it works correctly.

Has anybody else experienced this and maybe even found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking out the tip now works. I don't know exactly what caused it to work now and not then, but problem solved :-) .